# odp.net mixes up / caches clob column

Tags: asp.net, oracle, nhibernate, odp.net

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application where I'm using NHibernate 3.0 with ODP.NET (newest version) to access a Oracle Express 10g database. All is working fine except the CLOB column is getting mixed up in my objects.

**Example:**

*Http request /product/1/:*

All returned columns values are OK.

*Http request /product/2/:*

All returned columns values are OK, except the CLOB column. The returned CLOB column is from the previous loaded object.

**The problem disappears when disabling connection pooling.**

But I'd like to use connection pooling and it doesn't feels right as a solution. Is this a bug in the ODP.NET or are I'm missing some built-in "feature"?

Comment: It way be related to this Nhibernate bug, http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar [problem](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2200587&tstart=0) and setting "Statement Cache Purge=true" in the connectionstring solved it. But I admit it's a very strange case because it occurs only with clob.

Answer (score 0):

May you could try to set the `metadata pooling` attribute to `false`, when declaring ODP's connection string. See doc: [Supported Connection String Attributes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm#CJAEDBGH)

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks, unfortunately this doesn't makes a difference.